# Creating routes inside a private route with react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Currently using `react-router-dom` `6.1.1` and I'm working with a `private route`.

Inside this `private route` I usually had other routes (so that I can keep my `Sidebar` on them).

My code looks like this

```js
// App.tsx

const RequireAuth: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ children, redirectTo }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = Auth.isLogedIn()
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />
}

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
                <Home />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
// Home/index.tsx

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <Sidebar sections={sidebarOptions(t)} />

      <Routes>
        {routes.map(({ breadCrumbtitle, link, component }, index) => (
          <Route path={link} key={index}>
            {component ? component : <p>[{breadCrumbtitle}] To be done</p>}
          </Route>
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

So... This setup worked with `v5` but it seems to be something that doesn't really work with `v6`.
What can I do if I still want to keep the `Sidebar` for all the routes once I'm logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to my issue.
Doing what Drew Reese suggested only worked to a certain point since I was being led to a route that, for `react router`, didn't exist.

For it to work I add to do

```js
// App.tsx

const RequireAuth: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({ children, redirectTo }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = Auth.isLogedIn()
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />
}

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

          <Route
            path=""
            element={
              <RequireAuth redirectTo="/login">
                <Home />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          >
            {routes.map(({ breadCrumbtitle, link, component }, index) => {
              return <Route path={link} key={index} element={component}></Route>
            })}
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
// Home/index.tsx

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <Sidebar sections={sidebarOptions(t)} />

      <div className={css.contentContainer}>
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Using the `Outlet` seemed to be essential, don't know if it's something new on `react router v6` but seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Sure, the `Outlet` is for rendering nested `Route` components. I had considered suggesting rendering an `Outlet` in `Home` and moving the `routes` mapping out to Page but tried keeping it as close to what you had originally. Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the only issue is with the `routes` mapping, the `Route` components have invalid children, i.e. you are rendering another `Route` or `React.Fragment` as a child.

Move this up to the `element` prop of the mapped `Route` components.

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className={css.host}>
      <Sidebar sections={sidebarOptions(t)} />
      <Routes>
        {routes.map(({ breadCrumbtitle, link, component }, index) => (
          <Route
            path={link}
            key={index}
            element={component || <p>[{breadCrumbtitle}] To be done</p>}
          />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit creating-routes-inside-a-private-route-with-react-router-v6]

Comment: Thank you, Drew. I've tried this but it didn't seem to work but my answer did the trick!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70354421/10136219